# how sound quantity in a period of time is measured by?

Tags: acoustics, units

Let's suppose that I'm singing for 10 minutes and I obviusly produce some sounds, and let's imagine that I hold an instrument for measuring the amount of sounds produced within that period of time. I'm not interested in its intensity or quality.

-

Or, by analogy, let's call *"x"* the value of the unit of measurement and *"y"* the quantity I need to measure, so as to convey a proposition like->

*"I obtain x (unit of measurement) in 10 minutes".*

So, for instance, If *y* is the distance, *x* may be the km, so I may say ->
- *"I run 2 km in 10 minutes"*

If *y* is the quantity of sound, how should I call *x* here and how should I express such value ->
- *"I produced ... *x* in 10 minutes"* 
...?

-

**Which is the unit of measurement for the quantity of sound produced in a specific period of time?**

Comment: Energy is what it comes down, eventually

Comment: Watts.  Energy per unit of time.  In SI units, Joules per second.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no prior research.

Comment: Energy units if you're collecting stuff for a fixed period of time. The power could vary during that time, but the stuff is energy: joules, calories, therms, ergs.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answer is you measure the total sound energy that you released and is carried away with the sound and the unit is Joule. However, this does depend on intensity, the higher the intensity, the more energy per second and the more energy/sound is released in the 10 minutes.

If you want your measurement to be independent of the intensity, you can measure the number of whole waves (wavelengths) emitted (this would be more when singing high notes).

If you don't even want the pitch to influence your number, then you should probably state the total time for which you sing measured in seconds. For example:

"I produced a 9min 16s worth of sound in 10 minutes."

...because you had some silent pauses within the song e. g. to take a breath.